# Django REST API Media URL Structure Problem

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I send a get request to a question with rest api in django. It looks like "image": "question_images/myphoto.png", But I also want the media folder to appear like "image": "media/question_images/myphoto.png", how can this be achieved? question_images located in the media folder.

**I configured MEDIA_URL.**

**The Model.**

```
class Question(models.Model): TYPES_CHOICES = [ ("LAWYER","LAWYER"), ("REPAIRMAN","REPAIRMAN"),

]
SITUATION_CHOICES = [
    ("in","IN"),
    ("wait","WAIT"),
    ("closed","CLOSED")
]
question_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=TYPES_CHOICES,default="LAWYER")
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.TextField()
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="question_images/",blank=True,null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
situation = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=SITUATION_CHOICES,default="in")
```

**The Views.PY**

`class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly] queryset = Question.objects.all() serializer_class = QuestionSerializer`

**The Settings.py section**

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/mydomainname/staticfiles"

MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media/")

**The Serializer**

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Question
fields = ("user","id","title","description","image","created","updated","situation","question_type")

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(QuestionSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    data.pop("user")
    data.update({
        "user":UserRepresentationSerializer(instance.user).data
    })
    return data
```

**The Question URLS.PY**

router.register("question",views.QuestionViewSet,basename="questions")

Whenever I make a request like api/questions/question/question_id it returns as "image": "question_images/logo.png", in the request section but i want like "image": "media/question_images/logo.png",.

127.0.0.1:8000/media/question_images/logo.png

In addition, in the rest api part in settings.py, REST_FRAMEWORK = { 'UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL': False,
}
when i remove this code it look like this. 127.0.0.1:8000/media/question_images/logo.png
Yes, the media part is coming, but I want to remove the 127.0.0.1:8000 part